# Compare One Cell vs. a Row then enter data into another cell if there is a match

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out a way to compare one cell in Sheet2 vs. an entire row in Sheet1. If there is a match then I'd like to mark a requested row with an "X". The row to mark the "X" with needs to change because I'm comparing for numerous users, I figure I can just set a string for input. Once the single cell has checked down the entire row, I'd need the next cell in the column to check against the entire row and mark an "X" accordingly.

The long short of this is I'm making a database of software installed on 50 computers and I have a list of all possible applications and all installed applications per computer. Not every computer has every application, so I'm trying to automate a spreadsheet that will mark which computers have which software based on the data gathered. If this doesn't make sense please let me know. I understand logic flow and program in Powershell often but I'm not too familiar with VBA commands. Thank you!

Edit: Added picture for explanation.

Edit2: Added code below that I have. It seems to run the check but the c.Value is always wrong. It just doesn't quite check out. I tested CellApp.Select to confirm the range I want is correct. The loop just isn't checking the right values I don't think. For the example picture, pretend that the "List of Machine 3's Programs" is on Sheet2 and starts at A1.

[image: Example]

```
Option Explicit
Sub check()
Dim wsApplications As Worksheet, wsMachines As Worksheet
Dim CellApp As Range, CellMachine As Range
Dim listStRow As Long, listEndRow As Long, listCol As Long
Dim c As Range
Dim Counter As Integer

Set wsApplications = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set wsMachines = Sheets("Sheet1")
Counter = 3

'data start(row, col)on machines-list sheet
listStRow = 2
listCol = 1

With wsApplications
    'find last machine in list
    listEndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, listCol).End(xlUp).Row
    'Set CellApp Range
    Set CellApp = Range("A2", Cells(listEndRow, 1))

    For Each c In CellApp.Cells
    'For each cell in the CellApp Range...
        Set CellMachine = Cells(1, Counter)
        Counter = Counter + 1
        'Defines CellMachines as Cell "1,3" then "1,4" then "1,5" etc...

        If c.Value = CellMachine.Value Then
        'If the cell in CellApp is equal to the cell that is currently CellMachine
            wsMachines.Cells(4, CellMachine.Column).Value = "X"
            'Mark an X underneath the column that matches up. Designated Row 4 for a test.
        End If
     Next c

End With
```

Comment: Can you show an image on what the layout looks like?

Comment: Updated with a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method outlined below.  This assumes that the mc/program data is presented as per the image below and your 'matrix' is presented as per your Q.  Adjust the sheet names and data positions in the code to suit.

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub check()
Dim wsList As Worksheet, wsMatrix As Worksheet
Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim listStRow As Long, listEndRow As Long, listCol As Long, n As Long
Dim matHdr As Long, matCol As Long
Dim mcNo As String, progNo As String

Set wsList = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set wsMatrix = Sheets("Sheet1")

'data start(row, col)on machines-list sheet
listStRow = 2
listCol = 1

'start position of matrix (row, col) to be filled
matHdr = 1
matCol = 1

    With wsList
        'find last machine in list
        listEndRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, listCol).End(xlUp).Row
            'for each mc in list
            For n = listStRow To listEndRow
                'construct matrix intersect 'headers' for mc and program
                mcNo = "Machine " & CStr(.Cells(n, listCol).Value)
                progNo = "Program " & CStr(.Cells(n, listCol).Offset(0, 1).Value)
                    'populate matrix with "X"
                    With wsMatrix
                        Set r = .Columns(matCol).Find(mcNo, , , xlWhole)
                            If Not r Is Nothing Then
                                Set c = .Rows(matHdr).Find(progNo, , , xlWhole)
                                    If Not c Is Nothing Then
                                        Intersect(r.EntireRow, c.EntireColumn) = "X"
                                    End If
                            End If
                    End With
            Next n
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I ran this with the table you made and it doesn't do anything. What should it be doing? I'm a little confused.

Comment: Perhaps first check the data set up.  1. In the code, have you set YOUR values for the variables: listStRow, listCol, matHdr an matCol and the two worksheet names? 2. Is the format of your machine/program data in the sheet wsList and in the format I have specified in the image?  Note this is slightly different to how you have it specified at present. 3. If you select matrix sheet when you run the code, you should see the table being populated with "X"s as per the comments in the code. 4. Step through the code to check its progress.

Comment: I've just had another look at this and it is likely that you should change matHdr in the code to 2.  This means that the matrix header will be on row 2 as per your image.  In my testing I have it positioned at row 1.

Comment: Barry, I updated the initial post with some code I have worked out. I thought it would make sense but it doesn't seem to work out going across the sheets like that.

Comment: Ok, it works for me so let's make sure you understand and set the variables first.  Assuming that you revert back to the original code: set 'matHdr' to the row number of your row with Program 1, Program 2 etc..  Set 'matCol' to the column number of your column with Machine 1, Machine 2 etc.  Similarly, set  'listStRow' to be the row number on which your newly formatted machines and programs list starts, and 'listCol' to be the column number of your (newly formatted) "Machine No" column.  This new list should be in the exact format as my image, not as your original illustration.

Comment: I got this to work Barry. Thanks for your explanation and thank you for your time and patience.